# How to only show the first component of this type per section?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

I have x amount of sections, they have x amount of subsections, and they will show a little popup if a condition is true, but it could be the case that the condition could be true for more that one per section, but I only want to show the first popup per section.

I've tried with :first-of-type, (:not), setting an id to the popups, all to set a display: none to all the elements of the section that are not the first of his type.

```
<div>
   <section>
      <Subsection><PopUp /> </Subsection>
      <Subsection> </Subsection>
      <Subsection><PopUp /> </Subsection>
   </section>
   <section>
      <Subsection> </Subsection>
      <Subsection> </Subsection>
      <Subsection><PopUp /> </Subsection>
   </section>

   <section>
      <Subsection> </Subsection>
      <Subsection><PopUp /> </Subsection>
      <Subsection><PopUp /> </Subsection>  
      <Subsection><PopUp /> </Subsection>
      <Subsection> </Subsection>
   </section>
<div>
```

And for the css, I'm handling with emotion/styled, but any code that works with regular css will work for me.

```
section {
 ...
 .PopUp:first-of-type {
   display: none
 }
```

}

This is just an example, I have several more styles, components and classes, but any solution that works with this will work for my original code.

But, for the information, this is the styled component.

```
export const ProWrapper = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 35px;
  display: ${({ open }) => !open && 'none'};
`; /popup component/

export const SectionWrapper = styled.div`
  ${ProWrapper}:first-of-type {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
`; /section component/
```

In the example I set opacity: 0.7, and all the popups in the page got this rule, not just the first-of-type

**UPDATE:**

I solved it with javascript, in an easier way that I thought, javascript was my first option, but I could't make it work the first time.

Solution: I create a flag = false per section, the popup will only render if the flag is false, and I set the flag value to be true when the popup gets rendered.

Still, I don't understand why I couldn't get access to the first-of-type via css, so, I'll not close the issue since the problem of handle this via css is still open.

Comment: have you tried `section Subsection:not(:first-child) Popup` ?

Comment: Yes, @mulsun, but it only sets the rules for the popups in the subsction, and my intention is only render one popup per section, not per subsection.

Comment: `section Subsection:not(:first-child) Popup {display: none}` hides each section's first subsection's popup. Or did i not get it? Can you provide jsfiddle?